# What is this TRACKER process?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, directory, process

I saw this process called tracker. Just want to know if this is normal or not as tracker sounds somewhat scary.

It is situated in this Location: `/usr/lib/tracker`.

[image: alt]

[image: alt]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) is a filesystem indexer, metadata storage system and search tool.

---

If you ever wants to know where a file comes from use `dpkg -S`:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-write
tracker-extract: /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-writeback
```

Then to get information on it:

```
$ apt-cache show tracker-extract 
...
Description-en: metadata database, indexer and search tool - metadata extractors
 This package contains the metadata extractors.
 .
 Tracker is an advanced framework for first class objects with associated
 metadata and tags. It provides a one stop solution for all metadata, tags,
 shared object databases, search tools and indexing.
Description-md5: a749e5cb124710e079ed17d295038c12
Homepage: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker
```