# What is a `tracker3` folder inside `/home/.cache`? Is it safe?

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, filesystem

I found a hidden folder on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS file → `/home/.cache/tracker3`:

[image: photo showing the tracker3 directory]

Is it a normal folder? Is it safe to have a `tracker3` folder in my installation? There are files inside the `tracker3` folder. Can I delete the `tracker3` folder and the files inside it?

Comment: Most likely this folder was created by [this search engine](https://tracker.gnome.org/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this TRACKER process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254196/what-is-this-tracker-process)

Answer (score 4):

As the other comment says, it's a local file indexing process. If like me you don't need it or don't want it (e.g. it's a useless feature consuming resources) try this to disable it. It's the only way I have found to get rid of it:

```
systemctl --user mask tracker-extract-3.service tracker-miner-fs-3.service tracker-miner-rss-3.service tracker-writeback-3.service tracker-xdg-portal-3.service tracker-miner-fs-control-3.service
tracker3 reset -s -r
```

The above might not remove the .cache files but should stop it running.

I can see why it's included by default with Ubuntu as some might want it, but I think it should be disabled if you disable the `Search` features in `Settings -> Search` but for whatever reason it is not. It still runs and consumes resources. I don't know why...

Answer (score 4):

The `/home/.cache/tracker3` directory is created by [Tracker](https://tracker.gnome.org/), a file indexing process for GNOME. It consists of a filesystem indexer and search engine, *Tracker Miner FS*, and the database library *Tracker SPARQL*.

Tracker is used by various applications of the GNOME environment to provide search results. For example this is the application that is used to search from the overview or from Files (Nautilus). Here is [a list of applications](https://tracker.gnome.org/overview/) that use Tracker:

> - [**Books**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Books) — uses Tracker Miner FS to find ebooks
> - [**Boxes**](https://apps.gnome.org/app/org.gnome.Boxes/) — uses Tracker Miner FS to find VM images
> - [**Documents**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Documents) — uses Tracker Miner FS to find documents
> - [**Files**](https://apps.gnome.org/app/org.gnome.Nautilus/) — uses Tracker Miner FS for full-text search within files
> - [**Games**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Games) — uses Tracker Miner FS to find games
> - [**Music**](https://apps.gnome.org/app/org.gnome.Music/) — uses Tracker Miner FS to find music and store playlist data
> - [**Notes**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Notes) — uses Tracker SPARQL to store notes
> - [**Photos**](https://apps.gnome.org/app/org.gnome.Photos/) — uses Tracker Miner FS to find photos and Tracker SPARQL to store album data
> - [**Usage**](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-usage) — uses Tracker Miner FS to measure disk usage
> - [**Videos**](https://apps.gnome.org/app/org.gnome.Totem/) — uses Tracker Miner FS to find video content
> - [**Health**](https://apps.gnome.org/app/dev.Cogitri.Health/) — uses Tracker SPARQL to store health data

While the name "Tracker" might be a bit alarming (since "tracking" frequently refers to [web tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_tracking), which raises privacy concerns), here is used as "data indexing", and there is no danger or privacy issue associated with the process.

The `/home/.cache/tracker3` directory is used to store Tracker's data and you don't need to delete it. Deleting it will do no harm on your system, though. It will just make Tracker reindex your system and will consume some resources until it does it, unless you completely disable it.

In any case, I don't recommend disabling Tracker since it's a core part of GNOME and may cause loss of functionality. If, nevertheless, you want to disable it, you can run the command provided in [codlord's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1487341/618353).