# Samba connection to $HOME downloading lots

Tags: networking, samba

I have a CIFS drive mounted in fstab to a dir in my HOME.  Its a Windows system on the other side.  I noticed today that conky is displaying a constant 2-4 MBps download, and a smaller but constant upload.  I ran nethog and it showed a process with this systems IP and the IP of the Windows system as the culprit.

Now that I mounted the drives in /smb the data has stopped.

I know this isn't "Ask Windows", but any ideas what might have been happening?  Or how to find out?

Comment: At a guess, when you mount it in your home it gets indexed for the desktop's search feature - see [What is a `tracker3` folder inside `/home/.cache`? Is it safe?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487330/what-is-a-tracker3-folder-inside-home-cache-is-it-safe)

Comment: Oh, so you think my Ubuntu box was indexing the Windows drives?Anything in the tracker3 data I could look at to confirm this?

I had two other Linux systems also mounted in my home, I hadn't noticed any such activity with those.